# Optaplanner - compare multiple solutions in the same solving process

Tags: optaplanner

While generating a solution, I want to put some constraints about multiple schoolclasses timetable. For example, i want to check if the same teacher has no two timeslots (in lessons) on two timetables. So, I want to compare two timeslots (two lessons) in two different timetables.
I don't know how.

I'm using a ConstraintProvider class :

```java
public class TimeTableConstraintsProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[] {
                timeSlotConflictPenalty(constraintFactory),
        };
    }
   
    public Constraint timeSlotConflictPenalty(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory
                .from(Lesson.class)
                .join(Lesson.class)
                .filter(Lesson::isOverlapping)
                .penalize("time slot conflict", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
    }
}
```

I have this Planning Solution :

```java
@PlanningSolution
public class TimeTable {

    private String id;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Lesson> lessons;

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "timeSlotRange")
    private List<TimeSlot> timeSlots;

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<SchoolRoom> schoolRooms;

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<Course> courses;

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<Teacher> teachers;

    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<SchoolClass> schoolClasses;

    @PlanningScore
    private HardSoftScore score;

    private SolverStatus solverStatus;
    //...
}
```

Here is the Lesson entity :

```java
@PlanningEntity
public class Lesson {

    @PlanningId
    private Long id;
    private SchoolRoom schoolRoom;
    private Subject subject;
    private Teacher teacher;
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "timeSlotRange")
    private TimeSlot timeSlot;   
    private SchoolClass schoolClass;
}
```

And a part of the solver method

```java
schoolClasses.forEach(schoolClass -> {
    final TimeTable timeTable = new TimeTable(clientId, 
            schoolClass, schoolClasses, schoolRooms, subjects, teachers, lessons,
            lessons.stream().map(Lesson::getTimeSlot).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    final SolverJob<TimeTable, String> solverJob =
            solverManager.solveAndListen(schoolClassId, id -> timeTable, 
            this::saveTimeTable);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I want to check if the same teacher has no two timeslots (in lessons) on two timetables."

- Either that's one planning problem, so one big timetable (merge those 2 timetables).
- Or you're doing "multi-stage planning" (see docs): in which case one solution limits the next one's. So after the first timetable is solved, it generates `TeacherUnavailable(String teacher, Timeslot timeslot)` problems facts into the second timetable.

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey. My problem is your second proposal : multi-stage planning. The docs talks about multiple solver phases but doesn't give examples of implementation. So, for now, I have only ConstraintProvider with some constraints and I don't know how to add multiple timetables conflicts in this ConstraintProvider (Java). If I understood correctly, I only need to add the first solution as a fact in the second timetable to generate it and only with constraint (ConstraintProvider) and so on. Right ?